# How to sort array with undefined elements in IE7 JavaScript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-7

I am having trouble sorting an array that includes undefined elements (a sparse array) in IE7. This works great in Safari and Firefox of course, and I haven't tried other versions of IE, but here is a simple example.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function runscript() {
    var myArray = [{id: 2},
                        undefined,
                        {id: 0},
                        {id: 1},
                        {id: 3},
                        {id: 4},
                        {id: 5}];
    myArray.sort(function compare(a, b) { return a.id - b.id; });
    var output = '';
    for (loop in myArray) {
        output += myArray[loop].id + ' ';
    }
    alert(output);
}
</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="runscript();">
</body>
```

The alert() at the end inexplicably shows 0 2 3 4 5 1. Removing the undefined element from the array correctly sorts it and the alert shows 0 1 2 3 4 5.

Is there a way to work around this in IE7 so that I can reliably sort arrays that include undefined elements? I don't care where the undefined elements end up as long as the defined elements are sorted correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing `for (loop in myArray)` to `for (var loop=0; loop<myArray.length; loop++)`:

```
function runscript() {
    var myArray = [{id: 2},
                        undefined,
                        {id: 0},
                        {id: 1},
                        {id: 3},
                        {id: 4},
                        {id: 5}];
    myArray.sort(function compare(a, b) { return a.id - b.id; });
    var output = '';
    for (var loop=0; loop<myArray.length; loop++) {
        output += (myArray[loop]||{id: 'undefined'}).id + ' ';
    }
    alert(output);
}
runscript()
```

when using the `for (x in object)` the items aren't guaranteed to be in in order. See also [Why is using "for...in" with array iteration a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/javascript-for-in-with-arrays)

(The above alerts `0 1 2 3 4 5 undefined`)

**EDIT:** Undeleted - I've tested the above and it works :-P

Comment: I was assuming that for (loop in myArray) would respect the natural array ordering after a sort, and in fact it seems to in Safari, Firefox and even IE7 (but only when there are no undefined values in the array). If I do an indexed loop as David suggests, it works across all browsers. Too bad, I was just starting to get used to the more compact loop syntax. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can modify your comparator

```
myArray.sort(function compare(a, b) { return a.id || 0 - b.id || 0; });
```

Comment: Hi Kunal, this seems to work but I have no idea why. Can you explain the comparator function a little bit?

Comment: Yes. Custom comparator for sort is suppose to return integer value ( +ve, -ve or 0 only ). In the above scenario, when the value (a.id) is undefined, the sort function return NaN which is incorrect.

Comment: @David,
It will throw exception if you try to compare the value like

if( a.id == 10 ) { 
 // do something. 
}

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your sort function is wrong as it is expected to return -1, 0 or +1, not a boolean value.
Use this instead

```
var arr = [.....]
arr.sort((function(a, b){
    if (!a || !b) {
        // Here you choose how to treat undefined/null elements
        return 0;
    }  
    return (a[index].id === b[index].id ? 0 : (a[index].id < b[index].id ? -1 : 1));
})
```

But just so that you know, that loop of yours is going to throw an error when trying to return the `id` property from the undefined element. Also, you should never use a `for..in` loop to iterate over an array, use either a loop with incrementing index or a reverse while like this

```
var l = arr.length; 
while (l--) {
    ..
}
```